# how to stop setInterval in JS in node-red..?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, node-red

I'm trying to code a function node in node-red which will give output as increasing numbers by 1 for every second when get `msg.paylaod` true from inject node and stop when get `msg.payload` "false" from another inject node.
it starts giving output but don't stop when payload "false" is injected.

**Node code:**

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"b6c9b219.90a478",
      "type":"function",
      "z":"a3d6aff.bd4935",
      "name":"",
      "func":"var i = 1;\nfunction increment(){\n    i = i + 1;\n    msg={payload:i};\n    node.send(msg);\n   \n}\nif(msg.payload===true){\nvar interval = setInterval( increment, 1000);\nif(msg.payload===false){\n    clearInterval(interval);\n}\n}\n\n",
      "outputs":1,
      "noerr":0,
      "x":700.5,
      "y":581,
      "wires":[  
         [  
            "12f2090c.587347"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"12f2090c.587347",
      "type":"debug",
      "z":"a3d6aff.bd4935",
      "name":"",
      "active":true,
      "tosidebar":true,
      "console":false,
      "tostatus":false,
      "complete":"true",
      "x":826.5,
      "y":473,
      "wires":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"26abbbf.05cf944",
      "type":"inject",
      "z":"a3d6aff.bd4935",
      "name":"",
      "topic":"",
      "payload":"true",
      "payloadType":"bool",
      "repeat":"",
      "crontab":"",
      "once":false,
      "onceDelay":0.1,
      "x":654.88330078125,
      "y":767.2833251953125,
      "wires":[  
         [  
            "b6c9b219.90a478"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"880341a0.dcab2",
      "type":"inject",
      "z":"a3d6aff.bd4935",
      "name":"",
      "topic":"",
      "payload":"false",
      "payloadType":"bool",
      "repeat":"",
      "crontab":"",
      "once":false,
      "onceDelay":0.1,
      "x":643.88330078125,
      "y":824.0999755859375,
      "wires":[  
         [  
            "b6c9b219.90a478"
         ]
      ]
   }
]
```

**Code of function node:**

```
var i = 1;
function increment(){
    i = i + 1;
    msg={value:i};
    node.send(msg);
     if(msg.payload===false){
     clearInterval(interval);
   }

}
if(msg.payload===true){
var interval = setInterval( increment, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Why you are setting payload values to integer ?? when you are expecting boolean in the next step

Comment: Are you wrapping this code with another function that you are calling multiple times ?

Comment: @ShubhDixit thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @SalmenBejaoui yes I,m giving object name "msg" input to this function node from inject node

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you don't (easily).

The better way to do this is by having the function send all the messages in the sequence at once using the format for sending [multiple messages](https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#multiple-messages). Then use the delay node to rate limit the stream so the messages are released once a second.

If you **REALLY** need (you really don't) to do it the way you have it then you need to save the internal timer in the [context](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/context) and retrieve it in the increment function to call `clearInterval()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this. please take look at my node code. also please suggest if it can be done some other better way.

```
[
  {
    "id": "b6c9b219.90a478",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "a3d6aff.bd4935",
    "name": "",
    "func": "var i = 0;\nfunction increment(){\n    i = i + 1;\n    msg={value:i};\n    node.send(msg);\n    if(global.get(\"a\")===\"off\"){\n    clearInterval(interval);\n    }\n}\n\nif(msg.payload===true){\nvar interval = setInterval( increment, 1000);\n}",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 450.5000305175781,
    "y": 508,
    "wires": [
      [
        "12f2090c.587347"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "12f2090c.587347",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "a3d6aff.bd4935",
    "name": "",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "true",
    "x": 699.5,
    "y": 686.9999694824219,
    "wires": []
  },
  {
    "id": "26abbbf.05cf944",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "a3d6aff.bd4935",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "true",
    "payloadType": "bool",
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "x": 305.8833312988281,
    "y": 430.2833557128906,
    "wires": [
      [
        "b6c9b219.90a478",
        "4fdb56dd.8ef"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "880341a0.dcab2",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "a3d6aff.bd4935",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "false",
    "payloadType": "bool",
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "x": 207.88333129882812,
    "y": 666.0999450683594,
    "wires": [
      [
        "4fdb56dd.8ef",
        "b6c9b219.90a478"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "4fdb56dd.8ef",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "a3d6aff.bd4935",
    "name": "",
    "func": "if(msg.payload===false){\n    global.set(\"a\",\"off\");\n}\nif (msg.payload===true){\n    global.set(\"a\",\"on\");\n}\nmsg={payload:global.get(\"a\")}\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 202.26666259765625,
    "y": 554.2332458496094,
    "wires": [
      []
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This is the second option I described in my answer.